# Why is $_COOKIE[$name] returning null when it has a value?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, cookies

I'm writing a function that gets called every time you click on some links with  data-id attributes. I want to add the ids in an array and set them in a cookie but I cannot read the cookie. Here's what I have so far:

```
function add_this_id($the_id) {
  $name = "mycookie";
  /* line below is the issue: */
  $value = isset( $_COOKIE[$name] ) ? json_decode($_COOKIE[$name], true) : array();
  $value[] = $the_id; 
  $expire = time() + (60*60*24); //expire in 24 hours

  setcookie($name, json_encode($value), $expire, '/');
  $_COOKIE[$name] = json_encode($value);

  print_r($value);
  print_r(json_decode($_COOKIE[$name], true));

  die();
}
```

The first time it works and a cookie is created and I can inspect and see the ID as the cookie's value. However on the second attempt because the cookie already exists, line 2 of the function `json_decode($_COOKIE[$name], true)` is returning null instead of an array so I cannot append the new ID to it. So I tried wrapping it in an array like so:

```
$value = isset( $_COOKIE[$name] ) ? array(json_decode($_COOKIE[$name], true)) : array();
```

But all that does is returning an empty array so I can set the current ID and now I'm stuck in a loop where I keep starting from an empty array and can never append the IDs. Why am I not able to read `$_COOKIE[$name]` after it's being set? Any ideas?

Comment: @RyanVincent I tried both dumps and the first one just reiterated my own finding that the cookie is coming back null. I also dumped the id and it shows that I'm correctly setting the ids. I don't understand why when I inspect the cookie through the browser I do see a single ID string in there but when I try to read it, it comes back as null.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right, I have test online.

[enter link description here](https://eval.in/636606)

Comment: Say you run the function twice with two different ids. print_r(json_decode($_COOKIE[$name], true)); is only showing the one id not multiple ids.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think what's happening with your link is that the cookie is turned off so it start with an empty array every time, so it skips the buggy part of my function where it cannot read the previous cookie value.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code :

```
function add_this_id($the_id) {
    $name = "mycookie";
    $value = isset( $_COOKIE[$name] ) ? json_decode($_COOKIE[$name],   true) : array();
    echo "Value From Cookie";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($value);
    array_push($value, $the_id); // Changed HERE
    $expire = time() + (60*60*24); //expire in 24 hours

    setcookie($name, json_encode($value), $expire);
    $_COOKIE[$name] = json_encode($value);
    print_r(json_decode($_COOKIE[$name], true));
    die();
}
  add_this_id('123'); //FIRST ATTEMPT
  add_this_id('234'); //SECOND ATTEMPT REMOVE FIRST ATTMEPT LINE
```

OUTPUT :

```
//First Attempt  
Value From Cookie
Array
(
)
Array
(
   [0] => 123
)

//Second Attempt
Value From Cookie
Array
(
   [0] => 123
)
Array
(
   [0] => 123
   [1] => 234
)
```

Comment: Seems like array_push is doing the same thing as my code, I think the buggy part is the second line in the function, when the cookie exists, it's not reading the value correctly so it cannot append to the value inside the cookie. When I check if $value is an array before appending the new ID, it does not say its an array!

Comment: I have just checked the code, it works fine, on the first attempt I have added '123' to the cookie, on the second attempt I have added '234', on the second attempt I have got two values in the line print_r(json_decode($_COOKIE[$name], true));

Comment: I think you are right and the function should work but as I've pointed out $_COOKIE is being read as null even if it's set. I'm doing this in WordPress and I'm writing this in my function.php and I'm calling it via AJAX. I don't know if any of this could be causing the issue.